# AWK failed to retrieve the token

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I am trying to get the tokens using awk. But awk is not working for the delimiter "( ". why is this happening?

```
echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F"( " '{print $2}'
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /( /
```

but if try it with ") " it is working.

```
echo "sad ads ) this should come" | awk -F") " '{print $2}'
this should come
```

What is the reason behind this? gawk is also giving same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the special character in character class

```
echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F"[(] " '{print $2}'
```

Comment: thanks but the delimiter is "(" and " ". if i try the same it is giving "ads" as the output. `#echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F"[( ]" '{print $2}'
ads`

Comment: I think you are missing space. even `FS` is giving same error with multiple delimiters. `# echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -v FS="( " '{print $2}'
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /( /`

Comment: @Dinesh Put a space outside character class not inside. If the space is inside, the character class will consider either `(` or `space`. Use this: `echo "sad ads ( this should come" | gawk -v FS='[(] ' '{print $2}'`

Comment: yes.. it worked. thanks. But can you tel me the reason why it was failing if i use "( " but not for ") "

Comment: @jaypal thanks. But still my question remains!! it should have treated `)` and `{`,`}` also as a special characters.but is is not. Anyhow.. thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Dinesh Basically `awk` looks for a matching `)` for the `(` you have set as FS and hence errors out. All you need to do is tell `awk` that it is not a special character by escaping it. Since `awk` takes `\(` as `(` also, you need to escape the `\\`` as well making it counter intuitive `echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F"\\( " '{print $2}'`. Hence `[]` is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

> "What is the reason behind this ?"

Note that the following works (GNU awk used throughout):

```
$ echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F'\\( ' '{print $2}'
this should come
```

But the following does not:

```
$ echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F'\( ' '{print $2}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /( /
```

`awk` does not recognize `\(` as a valid escape sequence and substitutes for it a simple but unbalanced `(`.  It does accept `'\\('` as an escaped parenthesis.

The [`gawk` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html) explains that Posix is purposely ambiguous on what should happen when a backslash appears before regular characters:

> **Backslash Before Regular Characters**
>
> If you place a backslash in a string constant before something that is
>   not one of the characters previously listed, POSIX awk purposely
>   leaves what happens as undefined. There are two choices:
>
> Strip the backslash out
>       This is what Brian Kernighan's awk and gawk both do. For example, "a\qc" is the same as "aqc". (Because this is such an easy bug both to
>   introduce and to miss, gawk warns you about it.) Consider ‘FS = "[
>   \t]+\|[ \t]+"’ to use vertical bars surrounded by whitespace as the
>   field separator. There should be two backslashes in the string: ‘FS =
>   "[ \t]+\|[ \t]+"’.)
>
> Leave the backslash alone
>       Some other awk implementations do this. In such implementations, typing "a\qc" is the same as typing "a\qc".

`(` is not a regular character but, apparently, gawk treats it according to the former case.

There a separate issue with the interaction of shell and awk.  Note that the two commands below differ only in use of single- vs. double-quotes:

```
$ echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F'\\( ' '{print $2}'
this should come
$ echo "sad ads ( this should come" | awk -F"\\( " '{print $2}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /( /
```

The shell treats `"\\"` as a single backslash but `'\\'` as two backslashes.